# Vim won't load plugins when I change the runtimepath

Tags: plugins, vim

Basically I want to move everything from ~/.vim into a separate folder, let's say ~/vim_config.

I added this setup my ~/.gvimrc

```
set runtimepath^=~/vim_config
```

If I do a :set rtp the ~/vim_config folder is at the top of the list.

But no plugins are loaded.
Colorschemes are loaded though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is not the solution you desire, but you could create a symbolic link instead.

```
ln -s ~/vim_config ~/.vim
```

Comment: I'm trying to push that folder into a git repository so that I can sync it across multiple machines, so a symbolic link won't help me.

Comment: Also I want it to be a different folder because I'd rather not clone into ~/.vim

Comment: Actually, I do this myself. You clone into your desired folder (~/vim_config for instance). Then you create a symbolic link to that folder. It works rather well.

Comment: Oh,now I finally understand what you meant.Works great now.Thanks.

Comment: @adivasile: You can create a bash script in your vim configuration that automatically creates symbolic links in your home folder, so you can just checkout your module and run the script.